# Loop over two objects simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create a table as follows,

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Independent Column</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>i1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>i2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>i3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>i4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>i5</td>
</tr>


</table>
```

where column 1 and 2 are data from  variable `@a`, and `Independent Column` has data from `@b`. I want them to appear in the same table, so I can't loop them individually as `@a.each` and `@b.each`.

Any idea to help me.

Comment: How do `@a` and `@b` look like?

Comment: What is the difference between `column 1` and `Column1`?

Comment: Have you tried to merge `@a` and `@b`?

Comment: `@a.zip(@b).each { |a, b| ... }`

Comment: @a and @b has different size is my issue

Comment: Is there any associations between @a and @b?

Comment: No, i handle this issue by zip two array with the size of bigger array, where the missing part of the other array is null

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the first whilst tracking the index, and get the value from the second one :

```
@a.each_with_index do |a, index|
  @b[index] # may be nil
end
```

However, it means `@b` should have an `[]` operator, which is the case of any array, but may not be the case for a linked-list, depending on the implementation.

The best way would be to build your collections (`@a` and `@b`) merged together, so you can iterate on only one collection and get both values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
@a.zip(@b).each do |a, b|
end
```